# Worklight Server API to identify Android or iOS devices

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using Worklight server 5.0.5. We have a need where we have to send some push notifications  ONLY to iOS users (no Android user). If I use notifyalldevices function then it sends notifications to every device (including Android).
Is there any other easier way to send push notification only to iOS devices (Without querying database)?
If there is no other way then can you suggest what query should I write to use notifydevice function(Where deviceid is a parameter)?

Answer (score 2):

Below snippet might help you.Please note that I didn't actually try this. Can you try it out?

```
userSubscription = WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription ("MyEventSource", userID);
var devices = userSubscription.getDeviceSubscriptions();
for (var i = 0; i  < devices.length; i++) {
 if(device[i].platform == 'Apple' ){
     WL.Server.notifyDeviceSubscription(devices[i], options);
 }
}
```